# Как убрать отступ у тега video?

Tags: css, html5

Видео вставлено на сайт с помощью тега  между нижней границей блока с видео и следующего блока возникает небольшой отступ, подскажите пожалуйста, как его убрать?

```html
<video autoplay loop>
    <source src="video.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
</video>
<section>
  Следующий блок
</section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Предоставьте рабочий код, включая html и css

Comment: video {display:block}

Comment: Приведите [mcve]

Comment: @programmer403 спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй `line-height: 0`.

Убирал такой отступ когда:

```
<div>
<video> видео </video>
<div>
<---- отступ --->
<div> следующий блок</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего так:

```
video {
  display: block;
}
```